# Is this true: Every open set $A$ contains a neighborhood whose closure is a subset of $A$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

This seems a very easy fact. But I don't know how to prove it.
Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: For an arbitrary topological space, this is not true in general.  (There is a counterexample with two points.)  Are there some assumptions you have left out?

Comment: This is I think equivalent to regularity. For counterexamples, look for a $T_0$ space that is not Hausdorff. There are also Hausdorff examples.

Comment: Oh sorry it should be in R_n, or maybe even a complete space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This holds in a regular space ($T_3$ space) and above, including a normal space ($T_4$ space).

1. A topological space $X$ is a regular space if, given any nonempty closed set $F$ and any point $x$ that $x\notin F$, there exists a neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ and a neighbourhood $V$ of $F$ that $U\cap V=\varnothing$.
2. A topological space $X$ is a normal space if, given closed sets $E$ and $F$ that $E\cap F=\varnothing$, there are open neighbourhoods $U$ of $E$ and $V$ of $F$ that $U\cap V=\varnothing$.

**Edit:** Here is the proof of your claim.

> Theorem: In a regular space ($T_3$ space), for any $x\in X$ and each open set $U$ that $x\in U$, there is an open set $V$ that $x\in V$, such that $\overline{V}\subset U$.

Proof: Let $X$ be a regular space and $x\in X$, $U$ be an open set that $x\in U$. So there exists another open set $O$ that $x\in O\subset U$. Since $O^c$ is closed and $x\notin O^c$, by 1, there exist open sets $O_1,O_2$ such that $x\in O_1, \:O^c\subset O_2$ and $O_1\cap O_2=\varnothing$.

Let $V=O_1$, then $V$ is open, and $x\in V\subset\overline{V}\subset O_2^c$ since $V\cap O_2=\varnothing$ and $O_2^c$ is closed. So $x\in V=\overline{V}\subset O\subset U$ since $O^c\subset O_2$ and $O\subset U$. $\tag{Q.E.D}$

Since a normal space is a regular space and $\Bbb{R^n}$ is normal, the above also holds for a normal space and $\Bbb{R^n}$. For $\Bbb{R^n}$, just replace any open set containing $x$ with a ball $B_r(x)$ centered at $x$.

Comment: Is R_n a regular space or normal space?

Comment: yes, metric spaces are normal.

Comment: The proof of the theorem fails if $O = X$, since we need $O^c$ to be non-empty, so in particular we need $X$ to have at least two points.

Comment: $O$ can not be $X$.

Comment: Why not? When we are dealing with $X=\{a\}$, we clearly have that $X$ is regular. However, if $O^c= \emptyset$, we have $O=X$, so we can take $V=X$ and we are done. So we do not need at least two points, but we need to consider the case $O=X$.

Comment: We don't consider finite points of $X$ here. $X$ is infinite.

Comment: @hermes Thank you for the proof!! But I think the set to satisfy the conclusion should be O1 rather than V?

Comment: @hermes Also I just started reading learning analysis through Baby Rudin, so I don't really know advanced concepts. I searched for the criteria for regular space and can understand the proof. But in terms of why Rn is a regular space I have no idea. Hopefully I'll get to that point someday. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @hermes Even if $X$ is infinite, then $U=X$ is open, and $O=X \subset U$ is open and contains $x$.

Comment: @Hetebrij, in that case it still holds for $X$ is also closed.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: there is a topology on the two-point set $\{a,b\}$ that will give you a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then this is true; just take a very small ball contained in your open set.

In a general topological space this is not true (assuming you want a nonempty set).  For example, in any irreducible space every nonempty open set is dense.  These kinds of spaces occur in algebraic geometry.

Comment: But is there a proof for this? I really have trouble finding all the limit points of a neighborhood. Since I need to prove all the limit points are in A.

Comment: If you want a formal proof, take a point $x$ in your open set $A$ and choose an open ball $B_\varepsilon$ centered at $x$ contained in $A$ of radius $\varepsilon$.  Then the open ball $B_{\varepsilon/2}$ centered at $x$ with radius $\varepsilon/2$ has closure contained in $B_\varepsilon$ which is contained in $A$.